# Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation #2

Tags: c#

```
    public static ItemCollection Deserialize(string file)
    {
        ItemCollection Items;
        ItemData[] _Items;
        Stream stream = File.Open(file, FileMode.OpenOrCreate);
        BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();            
        _Items = (ItemData[])formatter.Deserialize(stream); //Im getting the error here
        Items = new ItemCollection();
        Items.AddRange(_Items);
        stream.Close();
        return Items;
    }
```

Hello! I have searched all around the internet for this problem and nothing seems to help me. Keep in mind I have some experience in coding c# I take classes 1 time a week! So please if u could look at my problem and try to help me it would be So helpful!

Here is the exception - Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.

I looked at the exception snapshot it says - { "Member 'ItemData' was not found."}

I'm trying to make a program that serialize a book of information from my text boxes to a Text file. I got that working but i can not load the information back to the text boxes.

[This is my item data class]

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary;

namespace FurnatureSaver
{
[Serializable()]

class ItemData : ISerializable
{

    private string _Color;



    public ItemData()
    {
    }
    public ItemData(SerializationInfo Information, StreamingContext X101)
    {
        _Color = (String)Information.GetValue(_Color, typeof(string));

    }
    public String Color
    {
        get { return _Color; }
        set {_Color = value;}

    }
    public void GetObjectData(SerializationInfo Information, StreamingContext X101)
    {
        Information.AddValue("Color", _Color );

    }
    public void Set()
   {
    _Color = Color.ToString();
    }
    }
}
```

Comment: You also have Stack Trace for any .NET exception. What exact line is causing that error?

Comment: take a look at the inner exceptions if they exist

Comment: What are you trying to deserialise and why?

Comment: @ShadowWizard I imagine the line saying `//Im getting the error here`.

Comment: @Antonijn oh my... very true. Still, inner exception might contain something useful.

Comment: I'm trying to make a program that serialize a book of information from my text boxes to a Text file. I got that working but i can not load the information back to the text boxes.

Answer (score 1):

Does it change something if you write it like this ?

```
namespace FurnatureSaver
{
    [Serializable()]    
    class ItemData : ISerializable
    {
        public String Color
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        public ItemData()
        {
        }

        public ItemData(SerializationInfo Information, StreamingContext X101)
        {
            Color = (String)Information.GetValue("Color", typeof(string));

        }
        public void GetObjectData(SerializationInfo Information, StreamingContext X101)
        {
            Information.AddValue("Color", Color);

        }

        // I don't see the point of this method. 
        public void Set()
        {
            Color = Color;
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this will help